# Liberty profile not available as a new server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, websphere-liberty

I am having trouble installing Liberty Profile. I have downloaded and installed eclipse Juno JEE edition and installed the WAS Developer Tools from wasdev. This worked fine after I re-created the default software sites which for some reason were not defined out of the box.

Eclipse reports that the toolkit is installed when I look at the list of installed software. However when I come to create a server instance there is no Liberty Profile option. The only entry under IBM is "IBM WebSphere v6.0".

Am I missing something? I am running on Windows 7 64bit. I have both a Oracle and IBM JRE installed and I have tried both by updating the -vm option in the eclipse.ini file. I have tried -clean. Nothing seems to let me create a Liberty Profile server.

Comment: Is that the original Juno release, or Juno SR2?

Answer (score 0):

The best and most reliable way is to install WDT in Eclipse is via Eclipse Marketplace. You will have the latest release available there for different Eclipse versions like Kepler, Juno, Luna. There are two editions of tools - one for full WAS, one for Liberty profile. So make sure to select the one you need. Developer tools work both with Oracle and IBM JVM.